# Kendo UI Widgets append <div>-elements at bottom of the DOM. Why?

Tags: kendo-ui

When using Kendo UI Widgets (e.g. Dropdownlist), there is some html-code appended to the bottom of the DOM. Why is that?

Inspect the demo site: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/index.html

Problem:
When reloading some content using AJAX, these html-code-fragments are getting appendend a second time. So some divs with same ID's are duplicated which causes some errors when using jquery-id-selectors. Can I prevent Kendo from duplicating these html-fragments?

Comment: This elements are required by KendoUI for work. If they are appended multiple times means that you are creating a new widget instead of reusing the previous one or destroying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These elements are the Widget's dropdown popup - there is one for each Widget that has such a popup. If you replace the Widget in the DOM and re-initialize it, be sure to [destroy it first](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#methods-destroy) - this will remove the popup elements from the DOM (and additionally will destroy the Widget's object, thus preventing memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks! That's working! But how would you destroy all these kendo elements when you don't know which are loaded in a specific site? Do I have to find them by jQuery? Or is there some unload-event-listener? (Context: I have a rather huge web application, and content is loaded by AJAX in to the main-div, so I don't know the content of each and every page)

Comment: There is a method kendo.destroy() in core which takes a container as an argument, and destroys everything Kendo in it.

Comment: Very helpful @Bundyo! http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/kendo#methods-destroy

Comment: This doesn't answer the question stated, though. which is why does it append to the "bottom" of the DOM

Comment: The natural flow of the page is top to bottom, thus the elements at the bottom of the DOM are sitting over the rest of the page without even adding stacking context.